# How to use avail in a sentence

Tags: verbs

Is the following sentence incorrect?

> Instead of laying off the workers, the company decided to ask them to **avail** voluntary retirement.

I think it is correct, because **avail something** is a correct construction. But my book says **avail themselves of voluntary retirement** should be used. Though it is also correct but the original sentence is not incorrect.

According to the book a **reflexive pronoun** should always be used after **avail**, but in OALD I found **avail something** is a correct construction, using **reflexive pronoun** is not mandatory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No

The usage

> ... the company decided to ask them to avail voluntary retirement

is not correct. (Macmillan and oxford say that this form is current in Indian English only. I have never encountered it, but I am not skilled in Indian English.)

"to avail" means "to be of use or advantage"

It does not always require a reflexive pronoun, but in this usage it would.

"To avail oneself of X" means to take advantage of X.

"X does not avail" means that X does not function as a benefit, usually that it simply does not work.

"He tried X, but to no avail" also means that X did not work. (I saw this form used in a current (sept 2019) "Miss Manners" column on the Washington Post site so it is in current use, but I don't have a link handy.)

"He tried X but it availed him not". This is archaic, it also means that X didn't work, or didn't help, was of no benefit.

In modern standard English "avail" is most often  used  in the verbal noun "To avail oneself of" (where any reflective pronoun such as "himself", "herself", or "themselves" can be used). This means to benefit by or take advantage of.

#### Dictionary Entries

> - [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/avail)
> - [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/avail)
> - [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/avail)
> - [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/avail_2)
> - [Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/avail)